# How do native android media players make data persistent as well as reflect changes

Tags: java, android, mediastore

Presently I am trying to build a full fledged android music player. I am loading all songs, artists, playlists etc from mediastore whenever the app is loaded and previously not present in ram. This approach though reflects mediastore changes between app loads greatly increases loading time. How should I proceed to get agreeable loading times and also reflect any data changes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to load all music etc. You would simply fetch what you need as and when you need it.

Comment: Suppose I have a viewpager with song, album, playlist, genre and so on sections. At the bare minimum i need the name and id of each category. Still I have to query the entire database, only the filtering field will be narrowed. Now if I do query whenever I swipe the viewpager will the ui be smooth? I have 7.5 gb of songs btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a cursor to recyclerview adapter
in, the Fragment implement LoaderManager

```
 public class LayoutFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 

          getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, LayoutFragment.this);
    mAdapter = new LayoutAdapter(getActivity(),mRecyclerView,mLayoutId, mcursor);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In addition, in your adapter, adjust the signature

```
      public LayoutAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, int layoutId, Cursor c) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = c;
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    mLayoutId = layoutId;
}
```

and add a few methods because you need them from within the Fragment

```
       @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mCursor!=null) {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == mCursor) {
        return;
    }

    if (newCursor != null) {
        mCursor = newCursor;
        mRowIDColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
        mDataValid = true;
        // notify the observers about the new cursor
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
        mCursor = null;
        mRowIDColumn = -1;
        mDataValid = false;
    }
}
```

and in Fragment

```
      @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case LOADER:
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            final String criteria = null;
            String[] columns = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME,
            };
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, columns, criteria, null, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME + " ASC");
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    mcursor=data;
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    mcursor=null;
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a  viewpager approach in my app New Playlist Manager, one for all tracks, albums and artists. For each of these I have a Fragment each of which has a custom cursorAdapter.
I give you the example of all tracks:
 set up my columns:

```
        dataColumns= new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
    };
    sort_order =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +" ASC";
```

To populate my listView I use a LoaderManager
    in OnViewCreated

```
 getLoaderManager().initLoader(GALLERY_LOADER, null, this);
```

and

```
       @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (loaderID) {
        case GALLERY_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    dataColumns,
                    null, null,
                    sort_order);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

So when the view has been created, the LoaderManager fetches the necessary cursor which is then fed to the Adapter.
So for each of the Fragments, you only fetch the data you need. 
For Albums my Cursor Loader looks like:

```
         public class showallAlbumsFragment extends Fragment implements
     OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

          dataColumns= new String[]{
                    BaseColumns._ID,
                    AlbumColumns.ALBUM,
                    AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                    AlbumColumns.FIRST_YEAR,
                    AlbumColumns.ARTIST };
    sort_order =  AlbumColumns.ALBUM +" ASC";




    @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (loaderID) {
        case GALLERY_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    dataColumns,
                    null, null,
                    sort_order);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this gets you going

Comment: Thank you but I am using a recycler view in stead of a list view and there is no cursor adaptor for recycler view

Comment: It does not matter. You need to find out how to pass the cursor to recyclerview